# How does the electric field instantly reflect the divergence in a system?

Tags: electromagnetism, gauss-law, maxwell-equations

Suppose I have a decreasing charge ρ at the center of a sphere being carried away by a wire out of the sphere at a uniform rate. By Gauss law, the surface integral of the electric field normal to the sphere must reflect the amount of charge at the center contributing a certain divergence. However, relativity also tells us that the surface of the sphere cannot know how much charge is contained at the center instantaneously. How do we resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The divergence law states that the flux of $\vec{E}$ through the surface of a sphere is proportional to the **total** charge inside the ball it bounds.

The flux is a *signed* quantity resulting from dot-producting $\vec{E}$ with a unit vector normal to the sphere, multiplying by an infinitesimal area element and summing over the surface.  Just because you get a certain value for the flux does *not mean* that $\vec{E}$ is uniform around the sphere, does *not mean* that $\vec{E}$ points radially outward and does *not mean* that if the flux is constant over an interval of time, then $\vec{E}$ is also constant (over time) at any point on the sphere.

Looking at it from the perspective of a point charge - the charge emits an electric field whose value depends on the particle's velocity and acceleration - and that field travels away at the speed of light (decaying with distance).

Looking at it from the perspective of a point on the sphere - the electric field is a superposition of the fields coming from point charges all over space.  However, the field coming from different point charges, are coming from **different times in the past**, because the field from each charge is delayed by virtue of having to travel at the speed of light.  (The past time when each contribution to the electric field at a point originated is called the retarded time.)

Note further that when you compute the flux integral over a sphere, you're taking the **same time coordinate** for all points on the sphere, so in addition to a single point on the sphere being affected by different retarded times of different point charges, two different points on the sphere are affected by different retarded times of the same point charge!

As you can see, the integral defining the flux is very complicated and involves contributions from all point charges at varying retarded times.

Now, let's consider the example given in the original post.  The flux at a given instant in time is proportional to the total charge inside the ball at that exact instant of time.  The charge is not vanishing from the ball, but rather flowing out of it through the bounding sphere and decreasing *continuously*, crossing the sphere at its intersection with the wire.  Now, if you compute the electric field at the points where the wire crosses the sphere, the retardation of the electric field from the charges crossing the sphere is zero!  Because the charge is going right through those points.  That's why the electric field at the crossing points can respond *instantaneously* to the exiting charge, and as a result the total flux can change *instantaneously* to reflect the reduction of charge from the ball inside.  Furthermore, since the charge is exiting the ball continuously, the total flux is decreasing continuously - concurrently with the charge.

So the divergence law for $\vec{E}$ which seems to imply 'instantaneous action at a distance' does not actually do so.  It's consistent with the electric action travelling at the speed of light.  The law of local conservation of charge ensures that charge cannot simply disappear from the center of the ball (possibly reappearing outside it) - something that would require the flux on the sphere to respond immediately 'at a distance' from the center.  Charge must exit the ball through the sphere, which permit the flux to change concurrently with it.